# Wordpress plugin: Working with REST api

Tags: rest, plugins, wordpress, frontend

Before I start, I want to tell you guys that I have no experience in anything Wordpress related. I do have worked in PHP and Codeigniter before.

**User Case**

- The user enters a preferred feature in a form (Air conditioning, etc.).
- When the user submits the form, the feature will be send to a REST API.
- The results of the REST API ( a list of cars with AC ) will be shown on the page.

It should roughly look something like this.
[image: Wireframe]

**What i have so far**
An empty plugin that is shown in the Wordpress admin panel.
[image: Plugin]

**Question(s)**

- How do create the front-end for this plugin?
- How and where do I create the form action?
- How do I access the form action?

**What I have/know so far**

I know there are some action hooks that will place your content in the header and footer by creating something like:

```
<php add_action('wp_footer', 'mp_footer'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your empty plugins php file place this:

```
function get_search_results(){
    $args = array( 's' => $_GET['term'] );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            echo '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "Nothing Found";
    }
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_search', 'get_search_results' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_search', 'get_search_results' );

function get_searchbox( $atts ){
    ob_start(); ?>
        <form id="searchform">
            <input type="text" id="searchbox">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <ul id="search-result"></ul>
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'searchbox', 'get_searchbox' );

function add_search_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'search', plugins_url( '/search.js' , __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'search', 'search_ajax', array( 'url'=>admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'action'=>'get_search' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_search_script' );
```

In your plugin's directory create a new javascript file - search.js and place this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#searchform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: search_ajax.url,
            data: { 'action': search_ajax.action, 'term': $('#searchbox').val() }
        }).done(function(r) {
            $('#search-result').html(r);
        });
    });
});
```

Now you can use shortcode `[searchbox]` in your wordpress page to get your searchbox.
In php you can get same result with `<? echo do_shortcode('[searchbox]') ?>`

**Explanation:**

1. When we add `[searchbox]` shortcode, it is processed and replaced with a form via `get_searchbox()` function.
2. In jQuery code On form `submit` we are sending an `action` : `get_search` (defined in `wp_localize_script`).
3. Server receives that request via `wp_ajax_get_search` and processes `get_search_results()` and returns an output.
4. In jQuery `done(function(r){` `r` is the response from server. Use that data to manipulate your html.

`action` is the essential part of REST api in wordpress. We need not have a url. Instead we define an action and for that action return a response.

Once you understand this, modify the action and response according to your need.

Helpful articles: [Daniel's](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/), [wpmudev](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my page doesn't change after inserting this code. Where should I access the REST api because i can't find any wp_remote_get ( $url, $args ); or something like that in your code.

My call should look something like http://localhost:8080/omniatravel-api/askSunnycars?featureList=AC

Comment: Edited my answer, added explanation. It will be really tough to create your own api based on url. Instead I used ajax to remotely get content from our server with action for which server returns a response

Comment: after some tweaks to your original code, i got it all to work properly. Thanks again!